# How can I Integrate AngularJS app with Microsoft Exchange through Node?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, icalendar, exchangewebservices

**The Stack:**

- Client: AngularJS & Firebase
- Server 1: Microsoft Exchange Server
- Server 2: NodeJS

AngularJS app loosely communicates with NodeJS through async [task-queues](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue). Client does not directly interact with NodeJS instances.

**The Problem:**

Perform simple operations on a User's calendar, with a task queued on a client and executed on a NodeJS instance.

**What I've Tried:**

1. [ews-javascript-api](https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-javascript-api): Works well, except there isn't a streamlined authentication mechanism. That is, it doesn't support OAuth authentication. In my opinion, managing each User's Exchange credentials is not a suitable solution.
2. iCalendar Events Subscription: (Still evaluating this approach.)

---

I guess fundamentally, what I am trying to do is have a User subscribe to calendar events in my app. I don't mind writing an API for Exchange Web Services but, it seems like overkill.

I am going to keep working on this, but if anyone knows of a simpler solution, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: btw, Oauth support for Exchange/EWS is limited to Office 365 version. no Oauth for Exchange server on-premise

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of the library ews-javascript-api.

have you taken a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43785262/5884960?
I have provided information on how to use OAuth in the answer to the question in link. caveat is that you have to on-board each Office 365 separately, you can not run a node daemon and connect to multiple Office 365 Organization (without complex environment setup with org on boarding steps).  This is quirks of Office 365 OAuth requirements not limited to the library itself. c# version have same limitation.

I have provided another library for helper authentications for ntlm and cookies, for Office 365 you just need ews-javascript-api.